# How make interactive indicators in plotly-dash depending on data

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm trying to write a interactive dashboard with plotly, but it is the first time that i use python, so i think i may misunderstood something.
I have a csv file called `tabela_simples.csv`, with random data, but the three columns that i'm using now is `Data`, that is a date with format day/month/year (22/04/2021) for example, `Primeira_dose` and `Segunda_dose` that are a integer.

The objetive now, is create some indicators that chage accordingly a date filter or `DatePickerRange`, after doing it, i was planning create others graphics. My code is quite long, and probaly messy or optimizable, but i'm putting a lot of effort into it.

```
import dash 
import dash_core_components as dcc  
import dash_html_components as html  
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from datetime import date 
df = pd.read_csv('tabela_simples.csv')
df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
df = df.set_index('Data')
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    ## cards   
    html.Div([
        dcc.DatePickerRange(
            id='date-picker-range',
            display_format='DD-MM-YYYY'
            ),
        dcc.Graph(id='card_fig')
    ]),
    ]) 
@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='card_fig',component_property='figure')] 
    [Input(component_id='date-picker-range', component_property='start_date'),
    Input(component_id='date-picker-range', component_property='end_date')]
)
def update_figure(start_date,end_date):    
    my_df = df[df['Data'] <= end_date & df[df['Data'] >= start_date]
    card = go.Figure()
    card.add_trace(go.Indicator(
        mode = "number+delta",
        value = my_df['Primeira_dose'].sum(),
        title= "Primeira dose",
        number = { 'font': { 'size': 50 }},
        domain = {'row': 0, 'column': 1}))
    card.add_trace(go.Indicator(
        mode = "number+delta",
        value = my_df['Segunda_dose'].sum(),
        title= "Primeira dose",
        number = { 'font': { 'size': 50 }},
        domain = {'row': 0, 'column': 2}))            
    card.update_layout(
        grid = {'rows': 1, 'columns': 2, 'pattern': "independent"},
        template = {'data' : {'indicator': [{
        'mode' : "number+delta",
        }]}})
    return{card}
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When i  try run the app,the terminal return two major errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_dinamico.py", line 41, in <module>
    [Output(component_id='card_fig',component_property='figure')]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Input
```

Or the most recent, that i don't have any idea why is happening

```
File "app_dinamico.py", line 44
    card = go.Figure()
    ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Maybe is just a silly mistake, but i watched so many tutorials and quesitons in stackoverflow and i'm more and more confused, so if someone explain to me what i'm doing wrong i would be thankful

Answer (score 0):

I think in the app callback you don't need square brackets, that's why the first error message appears. So if you replace the app callback with the following, the first issue should be resolved:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='card_fig',component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='date-picker-range', component_property='start_date'),
    Input(component_id='date-picker-range', component_property='end_date')
)
```

As for the second issue, you just need to modify the previous line (43) with the following:

```
my_df = df[df['Data'] <= end_date & df['Data'] >= start_date]
```

This should resolve the syntax issue.